# Merging two react applications into one

Tags: reactjs, redux, build, hosting, create-react-app

My story:

I want to launch very quickly one page, but I am really bad at CSS. I know react and wanted to get better there so I bought two application templates from themeforest. One is landing page, another one is kind of a dashboard page. All styled, independently works great. Now I would like to integrate them into a one application, so when user clicks on "login" in landing page he will be redirected to the dashboard application login page. Both applications are indepented. Both are made using CRA. Backed will be writted in .NET.

How should I do this? What are the best ways to do this? I could "copy-paste" some of the files of the smaller application (landing) to the dashboard app and change the root of the react, this is doable but will take some time to move everything, and build properly. Maybe there is another way that you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the react developers(not good in CSS) will be in a similar situation. There is no readily available solution I can think of. I suggest you to manually go through the landing.html and dashbaord.html and split it into 2 react components minimum. You mentioned that you know react, so it will be easy for you. The toughest part for you will be resolving CSS class conflicts. The two HTML files might be using the same classes. Here you need to go case by case or change the names of the CSS class for either landing-style.css file or dashboard-style.css file. 
Time to learn CSS basics. Good luck with your CSS learning.

Answer (score 0):

Why to merge the codebase, instead deploy them separately.

For example:
Let's deploy landing page to `www.example.com` and dashboard to `app.example.com`.

Once the user clicks on signup/sign-in just redirect to `app.example.com`.

This way you can focus on important aspects of each application.
Landing page for SEO and dashboard for new features.